# Python intersection of multiple datetime lists

Tags: python, list, datetime, intersection

I'm trying to find the intersection list of 5 lists of datetime objects.  I know the intersection of lists question has come up a lot on here, but my code is not performing as expected (like the ones from the other questions).

Here are the first 3 elements of the 5 lists with the exact length of the list at the end.

```
[datetime.datetime(2014, 8, 14, 19, 25, 6), datetime.datetime(2014, 8, 14, 19, 25, 7), datetime.datetime(2014, 8, 14, 19, 25, 9)] # length 38790
[datetime.datetime(2014, 8, 14, 19, 25, 6), datetime.datetime(2014, 8, 14, 19, 25, 7), datetime.datetime(2014, 8, 14, 19, 25, 9)] # length 38818
[datetime.datetime(2014, 8, 14, 19, 25, 6), datetime.datetime(2014, 8, 14, 19, 25, 7), datetime.datetime(2014, 8, 14, 19, 25, 9)] # length 38959
[datetime.datetime(2014, 8, 14, 19, 25, 6), datetime.datetime(2014, 8, 14, 19, 25, 7), datetime.datetime(2014, 8, 14, 19, 25, 9)] # length 38802
[datetime.datetime(2014, 8, 14, 19, 25, 6), datetime.datetime(2014, 8, 14, 19, 25, 7), datetime.datetime(2014, 8, 14, 19, 25, 9)] # length 40415
```

I've made a list of these lists called `times`.  I've tried 2 methods of intersecting.

**Method 1**:

```
intersection = times[0] # make intersection the first list
for i in range(len(times)):
    if i == 0:
        continue
    intersection = [val for val in intersection if val in times[i]]
```

This method results in a list with length `20189` and takes 104 seconds to run.

**Method 2**:

```
intersection = times[0] # make intersection the first list
for i in range(len(times)):
    if i == 0:
        continue
    intersection = list(set(intersection) & set(times[i]))
```

This method results in a list with length `20148` and takes 0.1 seconds to run.

I've run into 2 problems with this.  The first problem is that the two methods yield different size intersections and I have no clue why.  And the other problem is that the datetime object `datetime.datetime(2014, 8, 14, 19, 25, 6)` is clearly in all 5 lists (see above) but when I `print (datetime.datetime(2014, 8, 14, 19, 25, 6) in intersection)` it returns False.

Comment: I think you've answered the question about where the length difference comes from.  you have datetime.datetime instances which are in all of the input lists -- That only gets included in the `set` once, but 5 times in the list.  Second, are the datetime objects in your initial lists time zone aware?

Answer (score 1):

Your first list `times[0]` has duplicate elements; this is the reason for inconsistency. If you would do `intersection = list(set(times[0]))` in your first snippet, the problem would go away.

As for your second code, the code will be faster if you never do changes between lists and sets:

```
intersection = set(times[0]) # make a set of the first list
for timeset in times[1:]:
    intersection.intersection_update(timeset)

# if necessary make into a list again
intersection = list(intersection)
```

And actually since `intersection` supports multiple iterables as separate arguments. you can simply replace all your code with:

```
intersection = set(times[0]).intersection(*times[1:])
```

For the `in intersection` problem, is the instance an actual `datetime.datetime` or just pretending to be? At least the timestamps seem not to be *timezone aware*.

Answer (score 0):

Lists can have duplicate items, which can cause inconsistencies with the length.  To avoid these duplicates, you can turn each list of datetimes into a set:

```
map(set, times)
```

This will give you a list of sets (with duplicate times removed).  To find the intersection, you can use [`set.intersection`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/sets.html):

```
intersection = set.intersection(*map(set, times))
```

With your example, intersection will be this set:

```
set([datetime.datetime(2014, 8, 14, 19, 25, 9), datetime.datetime(2014, 8, 14, 19, 25, 6), datetime.datetime(2014, 8, 14, 19, 25, 7)])
```

Answer (score 0):

There might be duplicated times and you can do it simply like this:

Python3:

```
import functools
result = functools.reduce(lambda x, y: set(x) & set(y), times)
```

Python2:

```
result = reduce(lambda x, y: set(x) & set(y), times)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
intersection = set(*times[:1]).intersection(*times[1:])
```